# Inserting value into table in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I am new to java and trying to learn to insert the username and password and a profile image path into a Mysql database. When I run the following code, it will insert into table but the path filed of the table 'table_profile' 3rd column like as follows

if path equals `"C:/Users/Manohar/Documents/FileUplaodDemo/build/web/uploads/x.jpg"`

then it is inseerted as path equals `"C:UsersManoharDocumentsFileUplaodDemo uildwebuploads`

```
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "insert into table_profile values('"+userId+"','"+userName+"','"+path+"')");
```

Comment: Use parameter binding http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4):

User parameter binding like this:

```
stmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into table_profile values(?, ?, ?)");
stmt.setInt(1, userId);
stmt.setString(2, userName);
stmt.setString(3, path);
```

Let Java do all the hard work for you :)

Comment: And as a bonus, it prevents SQL injection attacks.